# Git: Change branch I have branched off of

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

For a new feature I have created a branch in Git from the current dev branch (not master) and implemented some changes locally but without committing.
Then I got sidetracked, and development has moved on. The branch I used as a base has been closed now, and there's a new one.

How can I change my feature branch so it's using the new dev branch as a base?

```
master --
     \-- dev 1
             \-- feature
     \-- dev 2
```

I want to move feature now that it branched off to dev 2 and then commit my changes:

```
master ---
     \-- dev 1
     \-- dev 2
             \-- feature
```

to the feature branch, without losing commits which others might have made, of course.

Comment: You need to look into `git rebase`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to

```
git rebase dev1 feature --onto dev2
```

(If I remember the arguments correctly, you may need `dev1^` but I dont believe so).

Comment: I get

fatal: Needed a single revision
Does not point to a valid commit: dev2

Comment: Well, does dev2 exist? Try git branch to get an idea. I just used your branch names.

Comment: @Jonas meant to ping you woops

Comment: If you haven't checked out the new branch locally, you can still rebase onto its remote. For me, this looked like `git rebase dev1 feature --onto origin/dev2`. Otherwise I get the "does not point to a valid commit" error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to add your changes that are not commited yet on top of the `dev2` branch. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

### Solution:

```
git stash save -u "My feature"     # stash all changes
git branch -d feature              # delete old feature branch
git checkout dev2
git branch -b feature              # create new feature branch
git stash apply                    # unstash all you changes
```